# Exporting html with arabic characters to pdf using django

Tags: django, python-2.7, pdf, xhtml2pdf

I am trying to export my html page into pdf using Pisa library in django, But I have problems with arabic characters when I get the pdf output
i visit this site https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/html-template-to-pdf-in-django/

here my code

```
from .utils import render_to_pdf #created in step 4
class GeneratePdf(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):    
        tar= u"محاولة"
        data = {'dem1': dem1,'dem2':dem2,'tar':tar}
        pdf = render_to_pdf('pdf2.html', data)
        return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
```

here the template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html"; charset=UTF-8">
<style type='text/css'>
@font-face {
    font-family: "DejaVuSansMono";
    src: url("/static/fonts/DejaVuSansMono.ttf");
    }
    body { font-family: DejaVuSansMono; }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <p>محاولة الكتابة باللغة العربية</p>
 <p>here the variable = {{tar}}</p>
 </body>
 </html>
```

i have symbols in place of arabic characters

Comment: try the package `django-pdfkit` https://django-pdfkit.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html

Comment: don't work. i wrote in settings.py 

import pdfkit
path_wkthmltopdf = 'C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf.exe'
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=path_wkthmltopdf) 
but i still have error : IOError: No wkhtmltopdf executable found

Comment: You need to install wkhtmltopdf, its a package called wkhtmltox https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html

Comment: thanks. already installed at C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf (and all Requirements (https://pypi.org/project/wkhtmltopdf/ except flashplugin-nonfree)

Comment: there is a solution using xhtml2pdf and pisa ?